# iOS get locale based description of number

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

Not sure if this is possible, but for my app I would like to get a locale based string that describes a number.

For example, if I had the number 10,000,000.

In english, I would expect the phrase "Ten Million".  However, in Hindi, it would be One crore.  Is there any properties in NSNumberFormatter, or NSLocale that could help me with this?

I have checked the docs ([NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSLocale](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html)), and havent found what I'm looking for yet.  Obviously I could write some code to handle these two cases, but I'd like a way that could work for any locale.

Edit: Thanks to leo for the answer!  Here is a small snippet of code that will get anyone looking for the same thing started:

```
NSNumberFormatter formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[self.formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"hi_hi"];
[self.formatter setLocale:locale];
NSNumber * myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10000];
self.numberLabel.text = [self.formatter stringFromNumber:myNumber];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle` style.

```
NSString* spelledOutString = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:@10000000 numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
```

Comment: I agree, this looks correct.  I'm going to test it out and come back

Comment: Thanks for this!  I will accept your answer, but I'm also going to post a small snippet of code in my question for future people